# Can't upload file to SuiteScript

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, netsuite, suitescript

I am trying to upload a Map/reduce type script to netsuite following a suitescript 2.0 training guide. I am receiving the following error: "***SuiteScript 2.0 entry point scripts must implement one script type function***."

I'm using the getInputData() and map() functions. Returning a reference object pointing to a saved search. Then extracting and logging the context value and the parsed context value (comparing json strings and js objects in the lesson).

Anyone see a syntax error, know what I might be missing, or what I can test for?

### Code:

```
/**
* @NApiVersion 2.x
* @NScriptType MapReduceScript
*/

define(['N/search']),
function(search) {
  function getInputData() {
    return { type: 'search', id: 'customsearch_iii_payments' };
  }
  function map(context) {
    var jsonResult = context.value
    var searchResult = JSON.parse(context.value);
    log.debug('JSON result' + jsonResult);
    log.debug('Search Result' + searchResult);
  }

  return {
    getInputData: getInputData,
    map: map
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried replacing the search reference object with a search creation that worked in a previous script, and replacing the id with an integer.

Comment: Very odd; looks correct to me. How are you trying to create the script? Double-check that the file you're selecting has actually been updated with this content.

Comment: @erictgrubaugh, thanks for the help! I solved it, please see my answer below.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see it now; glad you found it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a netsuite specific syntax error my linter didn't catch. My script definition wasn't wrapping the entire script, just the module declarations.

## Working Code:

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType MapReduceScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */

define(['N/search'],
function(search) {
  function getInputData() {
    return { type: 'search', id: 'customsearch_iii_payments' };
  }
  function map(context) {
    var jsonResult = context.value
    var searchResult = JSON.parse(context.value);
    log.debug('JSON result' + jsonResult);
    log.debug('Search Result' + searchResult);
  }

  return {
    getInputData: getInputData,
    map: map
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Also check the @NScriptType notation, in case you have ScheduleScript, netsuite will expect you to have a function called ¨execute¨ on the return object no matter if the syntax is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue for me was that my script referenced local files which I hadn't yet uploaded.

Upload other local files **before** creating a script record.

Answer (score 1):

double check for the `require` vs `define` keyword in the main method definition. 2.X `ScheduledScript` use `define`